# Timeout retrieving document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongo-c-driver

Sometimes we get this error message when trying to get a specific document:

```
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: 
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly 
respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because 
connected host has failed to respond. 

---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the 
connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established 
connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at MongoDB.Bson.IO.ByteBufferFactory.LoadFrom(Stream stream)
at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.ReceiveMessage[TDocument] (BsonBinaryReaderSettings readerSettings, IBsonSerializer serializer, IBsonSerializationOptions serializationOptions)
at MongoDB.Driver.Operations.QueryOperation`1.GetFirstBatch(IConnectionProvider connectionProvider)
at MongoDB.Driver.Operations.QueryOperation`1.Execute(IConnectionProvider connectionProvider)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at ... Linq statement in our code
```

It seems like it happens to document that are saved just recently.

If I run the query to get this document in MongoDB shell from web server it just hangs. Getting all documents including this document runs fine.

If I run the same query from another machine, everything is fine.

The only way to fix this is to change one property on this specific document from another machine.

Enviroment:

- MongoDB v2.6.3 on Windows Server 2012.
- C# / asp.net on Windows Server 2008 R2
- mongocsharpdriver version 1.9.2.

Process Monitor Screen Dump on web server running query in Mongo Shell: [image: Process monitor shows that TCP Send is done but no TCP receive]

Sample document/json that hangs from one server

```
    {
    "_id": "a635399137391923437",
    "Title": "Confectionery & Snacks",
    "NavigationAreas": {
        "Items": {
            "TopMenu": {
                "_id": "TopMenu",
                "Items": [
                    {
                        "Title": "C. Library",
                        "Url": "/ActivityOwnerDashboard/Index?activityOwnerDashboardId=a634395044701382271&activityownerId={activityownerId\n}&language={language}",
                        "Enable": true,
                        "IsPublic": true,
                        "VisibleToRoles": [
                            "Members",
                            "Editor",
                            "Administrators",
                            "Agency1",
                            "Agency2",
                            "Corporatemembers"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "Title": "T. Monitors",
                        "Url": "/Dashboard/Index?dashboardId=a635073303205437766&activityownerId={activityownerId}&language={langu\nage}",
                        "Enable": true,
                        "IsPublic": true,
                        "VisibleToRoles": [
                            "Members",
                            "Editor",
                            "Administrators",
                            "Agency1",
                            "Agency2",
                            "Corporatemembers"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "Title": "Administration",
                        "Url": "/ActivityOwnerDashboard/Index?activityOwnerDashboardId=a634988042201870012&activityownerId={activityownerId}&language={\nlanguage}",
                        "Enable": true,
                        "IsPublic": true,
                        "VisibleToRoles": [
                            "Editor",
                            "Administrators",
                            "Agency1",
                            "Agency2"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "Title": "KPI Monitors",
                        "Url": "/Dashboard/Index?dashboardId=a635288464367511308&activityownerId={activityOwnerId}&language={language}",
                        "Enable": true,
                        "IsPublic": true,
                        "VisibleToRoles": [
                            "Members",
                            "Editor",
                            "Administrators",
                            "Agency1",
                            "Agency2",
                            "Corporatemembers"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "Timestamp": NumberLong("6354421106745")
}
```

Comment: This is curious. Can you show us a problematic document and the exact statements you use to recall and modify it, both ones that do work and ones that hang?

Comment: This statment hangs in MongoDB shell: db.ActivityOwnerMetadata.find({_id: 'a635399137391923437'})

But getting all documents is fine:
db.ActivityOwnerMetadata.find()

Comment: Last time this happend, it did not help changing a value, we had to delete the document and insert it again. We also tried to restart the mongodb server / service, but it still hang.